# NativeScript IOS Safe Area issue with Children Action Bar

Tags: ios, angular, typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I uses the "@nativescript-community/ui-material-tabs" plugin to show tabs in IOS and Android.

[image: MD Tabs]

The problem is, the component "strangely" affect the top safe area in IOS (tested in IPhone 11 Pro) as you can see below:

[image: IOS Safe Area Issue]

I have troubleshoot and determine the issue to be when using MD Tabs and Nested Routing (where the Action Bar is defined in children tab).

Below is the associated components:

**app.component.html**

```xml
<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'
import { Routes } from '@angular/router'
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from '@nativescript/angular'

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: () => import('~/app/home/home.module').then((m) => m.HomeModule),
  }
]

@NgModule({
  imports: [NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [NativeScriptRouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**home.component.html**

```xml
<MDTabs tabsPosition="bottom">
  <MDTabStrip>
    <MDTabStripItem>
      <Label text="Featured"></Label>
      <Image src="font://&#xf015;" class="fas"></Image>
    </MDTabStripItem>
  </MDTabStrip>

  <MDTabContentItem>
    <page-router-outlet name="featuredTab"></page-router-outlet>
  </MDTabContentItem>
</MDTabs>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
...
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private routerExtension: RouterExtensions,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute, private page: Page) {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true; // as can be seen the action bar is hidden in the parent tabs component.
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // Init your component properties here.
    this.routerExtension.navigate(
            [
                {
                    outlets: {
                        featuredTab: ["featured"]
                    },
                },
            ],
            { relativeTo: this.activeRoute }
    )
  }
}
```

**home-routing.module.ts**

```
...
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: 'full' }, 
  {
    path: "home",
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: "featured",
        component: NSEmptyOutletComponent,
        loadChildren: () =>
          import("~/app/home/featured/featured.module").then(
            (m) => m.FeaturedModule
          ),
        outlet: "featuredTab",
      },
    ]
}]
...
```

And finally, the "featured" children tab component which defines the action bar (which takes up the space in the ios safe area)

**featured.component.html**

```xml
<ActionBar>
  <NavigationButton visibility="hidden"></NavigationButton>
  <GridLayout columns="50, *">
    <Label class="action-bar-title" text="Home" colSpan="2"></Label>

    <Label class="fas" text="&#xf0c9;" (tap)="openDrawer()"></Label>
  </GridLayout>
</ActionBar>

<Label text="You are in featured component"></Label>
```

Github link for testing:
https://github.com/limyandi/fuzzy-octo-memory

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem (but using BottomNavigationBar) and determined the issue was caused by lazy loading Modules (loadChildren) in app-routing.modules.ts. I worked around this by converting the module to a component and removing the lazy loading.

However, I like having my code organized into Modules and after a bit of digging found this was actually caused by including the property:

```
component: NSEmptyOutletComponent
```

Removing this property will fix the layout issue but introduces other subtle bugs. Instead [this bug report](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/2116) eventually got me on the right track. I created the WrappedEmptyOutlet as an alternative to NSEmptyOutletComponent as shown in [this repo](https://github.com/vakrilov/ns-status-bar-directive/blob/master/src/app/wrapped-empty-outlet.ts) and the layout problems have been resolved WITHOUT subtle side-effects so far :)